# R: how to let user to subset certain period of data through readline?

Tags: r, terminal, menu, tidyverse, readline

How can I lets user (in terminal) to chose certain period (e.g 2005-2009) from year column and subset data through this filter? using `readline()` and even also `menu()` functions

```
df <- data.frame (year  = c(2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010),
                  sale = c(11,12,9,9,4,12,18,36,21,30,44))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it with `readline` and `strsplit`:

```r
df <- data.frame (year  = c(2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010),
                      sale = c(11,12,9,9,4,12,18,36,21,30,44))

x <- readline("choose time span (e.g. '2001-2003'):")
# Enter: 2001-2003
    
x1 <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x, "-")))

subset(df, year >= x1[1] & year <= x1[2])

#>   year sale
#> 2 2001   12
#> 3 2002    9
#> 4 2003    9
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>